# Bash regex that returns short alphanumeric operator name from AT command AT+COPS

Tags: regex, bash, at-command

I'm using a bash script with the AT command AT+COPS=? which returns the following string :

```
+COPS: (1,"Orange F","Orange","20801",2),(1,"Swisscom","Swisscom","22801",7),(1,"Swisscom","Swisscom","22801",2),(1,"Salt","Salt","22803",2),(1,"Sunrise","Sunrise","22802",2),(1,"Sunrise","Sunrise","22802",7),(1,"Sunrise","Sunrise","22802",0),(2,"Salt","Salt","22803",7),(1,"Free","Free","20815",2),(1,"F SFR","SFR","20810",7),(1,"F-Bouygues Telecom","BYTEL","20820",7),,(0-4),(0-2)
```

And I'm trying to find a regular expression to match every short alphanumeric operator names. So here, it's :

```
Orange Swisscom Swisscom Salt Sunrise Sunrise Sunrise Salt Free SFR BYTEL
```

For example, in the group

```
(1,"F-Bouygues Telecom","BYTEL","20820",7)
```

It's the 'BYTEL' part that is interesting. 'BYTEL' could be also lower-case chars and numbers.

I tried multiple solution but they are all not 100% matching. For the moment, I'm using :

```
 grep -oP '"([a-zA-z])\w+"'
```

but it would not work in some special cases and is matching also the long alphanumeric operator names (first name between quotes).

Comment: `"([a-zA-Z0-1]+)"` works quite well, but regexp is perhaps too limiting in this case, perhaps use python/perl/awk and do proper parsin instead. Good luck! See https://rubular.com/r/wcvPFSWtCPVVxN

Comment: Do you always want the third element from each tuple-like expression?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes, I need the third element. The formatting is constant (except at the beginning / end of the string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sed variant

```
sed 's/(/\n/g' file | sed -n 's/.,".*","\(.*\)",".*".*/\1/p'
```

Your test string is in file, the output

```
Orange
Swisscom
Swisscom
Salt
Sunrise
Sunrise
Sunrise
Salt
Free
SFR
BYTEL
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pesky format to parse. I came up with

```
fugly command |
grep -o '([^()]*)' |
awk -F , 'NF==5 { x=$3; gsub(/\"/, "", x); print x }'
```

which is unsatisfying in some sense, but easy enough to understand I hope.

Demo: https://ideone.com/jH0NKj

Here's a simplified pure Awk variation with slightly different assumptions:

```
awk -F , -v RS='(' 'NF>=5 { x=$3; gsub(/\"/, "", x); print x}'
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/UvEXXH

Answer (score 0):

using a combination of sed and awk

```
sed 's/(/\n/g' file | awk -F, '{print gensub(/\"/,"","g", $3)}'

Orange
Swisscom
Swisscom
Salt
Sunrise
Sunrise
Sunrise
Salt
Free
SFR
BYTEL
```